# automapper inherting Profile returns extra properties in json

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

From what I read, the standard is to inherit Profile class in order for Automapper to detect maps. https://automapper.org/

```
public class GamerVM : Profile
{
    public GamerVM()
    {
        CreateMap<GamerVM, Gamer>();
        CreateMap<Gamer, GamerVM>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

If I inherit this class on my view model the Json is returned with extra properties:

```
 {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Ashton Heir",
    "tag": "Legend",
    "defaultMemberConfig": {
        "nameMapper": {
            "getMembers": {},
            "namedMappers": [
                {
                    "methodCaseSensitive": false
                },
                {},
                {
                    "prefixes": [
                        "Get"
                    ],
                    "postfixes": [],
                    "destinationPrefixes": [],
                    "destinationPostfixes": []
                }
            ]
        },
        "memberMappers": [
            {
                "nameMapper": {
                    "getMembers": {},
                    "namedMappers": [
                        {
                            "methodCaseSensitive": false
                        },
                        {},
                        {
                            "prefixes": [
                                "Get"
                            ],
                            "postfixes": [],
                            "destinationPrefixes": [],
                            "destinationPostfixes": []
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            {
                "sourceMemberNamingConvention": {
                    "splittingExpression": {
                        "pattern": "(\\p{Lu}+(?=$|\\p{Lu}[\\p{Ll}0-9])|\\p{Lu}?[\\p{Ll}0-9]+)",
                        "options": 0
                    },
                    "separatorCharacter": ""
                },
                "destinationMemberNamingConvention": {
                    "splittingExpression": {
                        "pattern": "(\\p{Lu}+(?=$|\\p{Lu}[\\p{Ll}0-9])|\\p{Lu}?[\\p{Ll}0-9]+)",
                        "options": 0
                    },
                    "separatorCharacter": ""
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Am I doing this correctly? Is there a way to JSON ignore these extra properties?

Comment: Did you try JSON ignore property attribute?

Comment: Your model should not inherit Profile. You subclass Profile to configure your model-to-model mappings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model should not inherit Profile. You subclass Profile to configure your model-to-model mappings.

```
public class GamerMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public GamerMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Gamer, GamerVM>();
        CreateMap<GamerVM, Gamer>();
    }
}
```

Then you load the Profile(s) when you create the mapper instance.

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile<GamerMappingProfile>();
    cfg.AddProfile<MyOtherProfile>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

Now your model is clean -- it only contains your properties and serializing doesn't require additional custom code.

**To auto-scan for your Profile**

http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Configuration.html#assembly-scanning-for-auto-configuration

Copied from the link above

```
// Scan for all profiles in an assembly
// ... using instance approach:
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfiles(myAssembly);
});
// ... or static approach:
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.AddProfiles(myAssembly));

// Can also use assembly names:
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    cfg.AddProfiles(new [] {
        "Foo.UI",
        "Foo.Core"
    });
);

// Or marker types for assemblies:
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
    cfg.AddProfiles(new [] {
        typeof(HomeController),
        typeof(Entity)
    });
);
```

Comment: ah i see, i have an IMappable interface where i've been doing it my way for earlier versions of automapper. I thought this profile class did it the same way. I like my way better :(. Imo, mappings should be a part of the class not somewhere else. But thanks!

Comment: do i need to add all profiles 1 by 1 or can't it just auto detect Profile class?

Comment: I have always loaded my profiles. I haven't investigated auto-detecting my configuration.

Comment: that's a mess, some of my apps have over 50 domain models and 3 different view models lol.. I think i'll stick to my existing infrastructure. ClassFinder.GetEnumerableOfType<IMappable>().Each(c => c.Map());